# Can we query a dynamodb table with a gsi index and use the last evaluated key for pagination?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a table with 4 fields

1. id -> hash
2. uniid -> global secondary index
3. email
4. status -> global secondary index

Is it possible to get all emails where `uniid` is `foo` using `LastEvaluatedKey` for pagination.

I am trying something like

```
var params = {
    TableName                : 'users',
    IndexName                : 'gsiuniid',
    KeyConditionExpression   : '#uniid = :uniid',
    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
       '#uniid': 'uniid'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
       ':uniid': 'valid-uniid'
    },
    ExclusiveStartKey: {
        'id' : 'id-from-last-query'
    }
};


dynamodb.query(params, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And i get the error, `The provided starting key is invalid`.
I checked the db, the starting key, which is the id of the above table, exists.

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: are you using LastEvaluatedKey value from the previous request? what is the client you are using?

Comment: Yes using `LastEvaluatedKey ` from previous request, using aws-js sdk on lambda

Answer (score 0):

can you change ExclusiveStartKey key?

```
ExclusiveStartKey: {
        '#uniid' : 'id-from-last-query'
    }
```